# 74ls139--are they supposed to do this?

Tags: digital-logic

So I am trying to get a [74ls139](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74s139a.pdf) to work, but am having a little trouble. I hooked up inputs a and b to flexible jumpers, and all the outputs to leds. I then went through all the input combinations, with each one giving the expected output. When I got to both inputs high, things started going weird. Only one led lit up, and the rest turned off. I though that maybe it was a problem with the led or connection to the led, but then I realized that then the led wouldn't have turned on for any of the inputs. I tried the same circuit with 10 different chips, but they all did the same thing. Is this an error in my wiring, or a problem with the ic itself? (video link below)

[video](https://vimeo.com/239912800)

Comment: Much better than a video would be some well-taken still pictures inline with the question (there's a button for that at the top of the editor) and a well-drawn schematic (there's a button for that too).  I'm not going to watch the video because I'm on a metered connection right now, which means that videos are particularly expensive.

Comment: Please show a schematic diagram showing how you have connected the IC and the LEDs.  This site has a nice schematic tool that you can access by hitting "Control-M" while editing your question.

Comment: Your question title says "74LS174", but the text says "74LS139".  Which part are you really using?  the '139 and '174 are very different parts.

Comment: crappy video, it's pretty much impossible to see your connections.

Comment: As you're asking engineers for electronic engineering help, you need to learn the language of engineering, a schematic. It's so frequently used that this site has a button for it when you edit your post, the diode/resistor/capacitor/pencil button (which does the same thing as ctrl-M) next to the picture button.

Answer (score 1):

Many beginners are confused by the fact that bipolar TTL (plain 74xx, 74LS, 74ALS and others) inputs source current, and will act as logic High with no connection.  To get a logic Low input, you must connect the input to directly to ground, or to ground with a low resistance - under 500 Ohms should work.

CMOS parts (74C, 74HC, or anything with a "C" in the middle) will have a very high input impedance, and may float randomly between High and Low if left unconnected.  Fairly high value (5 - 10K Ohm) pull-up or pull-down resistors can be used to force otherwise-unused inputs to a known state.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a good ground connection. (pin 8).

With many Ics a missing ground connection can be masked by current being supplied through any inputs that are grounded - if none of the inputs are at ground the chip loses power and it does not function correctly.

The chip can be powered through the inputs because virtually all ICs contain ESD protection circuits that often consist of a diode to each supply rail.

Also your title is incorrect - you say 74LS174 there but 74LS139 in the question.